# django cache downloaded file on browser side with login_requried

Tags: django, caching

Server side cache has plenty documents and is very convenient to implement. But More often I would like the sever to send `HTTP304` to tell browser the content haven't changed since last visit.

like this special use case, I would like authorized user to open a file for reading, and the file eventually won't change for quite some time. **how to tell browser to cache this file but before that authorization is still needed ? is this possible ?** 
I know the `login_required` decorator has conflict even with `cache_page` decorator